# Game of Life simulator, Python 3

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, game-of-life

Using Python 3.7.0, I've programmed a 'Game of Life' simulator. The output is displayed using tkinter. It's not meant to be limited to just Game of Life, though, as it's meant to also be used for a simple physics simulation project.

```
import tkinter as tk
#import pdb

class Cell:

    #ref_dict allows the coords to act as a pointer to the cell.
    ref_dict = {}
    """active_cells allows the grid to determine sim_cells.
    Thus, it reduces the number of cells the grid needs to simulate.
    """
    active_cells = set()

    def __init__(
            self, coords, size, grid_size, conditions = {},
            active_color = "black", inactive_color = "white", state = False):
        """Create a new cell.

        Positional arguments:

            coords ---------- Coordinates of the cell within the grid.
            Tuple (x, y)

            size ------------ Side length of the cell in pixels.
            Integer.

            grid_size ------- Side length of the grid, in squares.
            Integer.

        Keyword arguments:

            conditions ------ Dict of conditions the cell has.
            Used for complex simulations.
            Keys as names, values as floats.
            E.g. 'temperature': 50.4
            Dictionary.

            active_color ---- Color of the cell when alive.
            String or color reference.

            inactive_color -- Color of the cell when dead.
            String or color reference.

            state ----------- Whether the cell is alive or dead.
            Boolean.

        This object simulates a cell, which evolves over time.
        Here, the rules for evolution are from 'Conway's game of life'.
        """
        self.coords = coords
        self.size = size
        self.grid_size = grid_size
        self.conditions = conditions
        self.active_color = active_color
        self.inactive_color = inactive_color
        self.state = state
        """The cell won't update it's state straight away.
        Otherwise, it could cause a knock-on effect,
        changing the number of neighbors for other cells.
        To avoid this, the cell will calculate its new_state first.
        Then, it can set self.state = self.new_state after all updates.
        """
        self.new_state = False
        self.neighbor_coords = ()
        self.get_neighbor_coords()
        self.alive_neighbors = 0
        """This allows instantiation without variable assignment,
        by letting the coordinates act as a pointer.
        """
        Cell.ref_dict[self.coords] = self

    def valid_coord(self, coord):
        """Determine whether a given coordinate is within the grid.

        x coordinates are measured from the origin.
        Hence, they should not be >= to the grid_size.
        This would indicate it was referring to a column right of the
        rightmost column, due to everything being 0-indexed.
        Similar rules apply for the y coordinate.
        """
        (x, y) = coord
        return (0 <= x < self.grid_size) and (0 <= y < self.grid_size)

    def get_neighbor_coords(self):
        """Construct neighbor_coords."""
        (x, y) = self.coords
        self.neighbor_coords = tuple(filter(self.valid_coord,
        [(x + a, y + b)
        for a in range(-1, 2) for b in range(-1, 2) if a != 0 or b != 0]))
        return self

    def get_alive_neighbors(self):
        """Determine alive_neighbors."""
        self.alive_neighbors = 0
        for n in self.neighbor_coords:
            if Cell.ref_dict[n].state:
                self.alive_neighbors += 1
        return self

    def get_new_state(self):
        """Determine what the new state of the cell should be.

        Here is where any different rules can be configured.
        """
        if not self.neighbor_coords:
            self.get_neighbor_coords().get_alive_neighbors()
        else:
            self.get_alive_neighbors()
        if self.state:
            if not 2 <= self.alive_neighbors <= 3:
                self.new_state = False
            else:
                self.new_state = True
        else:
            if self.alive_neighbors == 3:
                self.new_state = True
            else:
                self.new_state = False
        return self

    def update_state(self):
        """Set self.state to self.new_state; reset self.new_state.

        Also will add/remove the cell from active_cells.
        """
        self.state = self.new_state

        if self.state and self.coords not in Cell.active_cells:
            Cell.active_cells.add(self.coords)
        elif not self.state and self.coords in Cell.active_cells:
            Cell.active_cells.remove(self.coords)

        self.new_state = False
        return self

class Grid:

    def __init__(
            self, size, cell_size, active_color = "black",
            inactive_color = "white", condition_dict = {},
            initial_active_cells = []):
        """Create a new grid.

        Positional arguments:

            size ----------------- Size of the grid in cells.
            Integer.

            cell_size ------------ Size of a cell in pixels.
            Integer.

        Keyword arguments:

            active_color --------- Color of a cell when alive.
            String or color reference.

            inactive_color ------- Color of a cell when dead.
            String or color reference.

            condition_dict ------- Nested dictionary.
            Coordinates as keys, dicts of conditions as values.
            Dictionary.

            initial_active_cells - List of cells that start alive.
            List.

        """
        self.size = size
        self.cell_size = cell_size
        self.active_color = active_color
        self.inactive_color = inactive_color
        self.condition_dict = condition_dict
        self.initial_active_cells = initial_active_cells
        """Only active cells and neighbors are simulated.
        Coords in self.sim_cells. This attempts to reduce CPU usage.
        """
        self.sim_cells = set()
        self.create_cells().set_active_cells(initial_active_cells)

    def create_cells(self):
        """Instantiate all new cells with required parameters."""

        """Conditions may not be specified.
        The if statement thus avoids KeyErrors.
        """
        if self.condition_dict:
            for x in range(0, self.size):
                for y in range(0, self.size):
                    Cell(
                        (x, y), self.cell_size, self.size,
                        conditions = self.condition_dict[(x, y)],
                        active_color = self.active_color,
                        inactive_color = self.inactive_color)
        else:
            for x in range(0, self.size):
                for y in range(0, self.size):
                    Cell(
                        (x, y), self.cell_size, self.size,
                        active_color = self.active_color,
                        inactive_color = self.inactive_color)
        return self

    def set_active_cells(self, initial_active_cells):
        """Set states of cells specified by a list to True."""
        for coord in initial_active_cells:
            Cell.ref_dict[coord].new_state = True
            Cell.ref_dict[coord].update_state()
        return self

    def get_sim_cells(self):
        """Get all cells that need to be simulated."""
        self.sim_cells = set()
        for coord in Cell.active_cells:
            self.sim_cells.add(coord)
        """This finds all neighbors of active cells,
        to determine which cells need to be simulated."""
        self.sim_cells.update(
            [(x + a, y + b)
            for a in range(-1,2) for b in range(-1,2)
            for (x,y) in self.sim_cells
            if Cell.valid_coord(Cell.ref_dict[(x,y)], (x + a, y + b))])
        return self

    def update_grid(self):
        """Update simulated cells, and update the set of sim_cells."""
        self.get_sim_cells()
        """Two loops are used to stop early death or birth of cells.
        The grid is meant to evolve as a whole each tick,
        and not cell-by-cell.
        """
        for coord in self.sim_cells:
            Cell.ref_dict[coord].get_new_state()
        for coord in self.sim_cells:
            Cell.ref_dict[coord].update_state()
        return self

class App:

    #Matches cell coordinates to the canvas squares.
    canvas_dict = {}

    def __init__(
            self, grid_size, cell_size,
            active_color = "black", inactive_color = "white",
            condition_dict = {}, initial_active_cells = []):
        """Start a new game.

        Positional arguments:

            grid_size ------------ Size of grid, in cells.
            Integer.

            cell_size ------------ Size of a cell, in pixels.
            Integer.

        Keyword arguments:

            active_color --------- Color of a cell when alive.
            String or color reference.

            inactive_color ------- Color of a cell when dead.
            String or color reference.

            condition_dict ------- Nested dictionary.
            Coordinates as keys, dicts of conditions as values.
            Dictionary.

            initial_active_cells - List of cells that start alive.
            List.
        """
        self.grid_size = grid_size
        self.cell_size = cell_size
        self.active_color = active_color
        self.inactive_color = inactive_color
        self.condition_dict = condition_dict
        self.initial_active_cells = initial_active_cells

        self.size = grid_size * cell_size
        self.grid = Grid(
            self.grid_size, self.cell_size,
            active_color = self.active_color,
            inactive_color = self.inactive_color,
            condition_dict = self.condition_dict,
            initial_active_cells = self.initial_active_cells)
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self.root, bg = "white",
            height = self.size, width = self.size)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.render_canvas(canvas_created = False)

        self.root.after(1000, self.refresh_display)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def refresh_display(self):
        """Update both grid and canvas."""
        self.grid.update_grid()
        self.render_canvas(canvas_created = True)
        self.root.after(50, self.refresh_display)

    def render_canvas(self, canvas_created = False):
        if not canvas_created:
            for x in range(0, self.grid_size):
                for y in range(0, self.grid_size):
                    if (x, y) in self.initial_active_cells:
                        #This specifies the corners of the polygon.
                        App.canvas_dict[(x, y)] = self.canvas.create_polygon(
                            x * self.cell_size, y * self.cell_size,
                            (x+1) * self.cell_size, y * self.cell_size,
                            (x+1) * self.cell_size, (y+1) * self.cell_size,
                            x * self.cell_size, (y+1) * self.cell_size,
                            fill = self.active_color, outline = "black")
                    else:
                        App.canvas_dict[(x, y)] = self.canvas.create_polygon(
                            x * self.cell_size, y * self.cell_size,
                            (x+1) * self.cell_size, y * self.cell_size,
                            (x+1) * self.cell_size, (y+1) * self.cell_size,
                            x * self.cell_size, (y+1) * self.cell_size,
                            fill = self.inactive_color, outline = "black")
        else:
            for coord in self.grid.sim_cells:
                if Cell.ref_dict[coord].state:
                    self.canvas.itemconfig(
                        App.canvas_dict[coord], fill = self.active_color)
                else:
                    self.canvas.itemconfig(
                        App.canvas_dict[coord], fill = self.inactive_color)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #This gives the default pattern of a Gosper glider gun.
    app = App(60, 5, initial_active_cells = [
        (25,1), (23,2), (25,2), (13,3),
        (14,3), (21,3), (22,3), (35,3),
        (36,3), (12,4), (16,4), (21,4),
        (22,4), (35,4), (36,4), (1,5),
        (2,5), (11,5), (17,5), (21,5),
        (22,5), (1,6), (2,6), (11,6),
        (15,6), (17,6), (18,6), (23,6),
        (25,6), (11,7), (17,7), (25,7),
        (12,8), (16,8), (13,9), (14,9)])
```

My skill level is a beginner - this is my first non-trivial project that makes use of OOP concepts like classes. Most of my previous projects have been algorithm-based, for example writing an algorithm to crack the Caesar cipher.

I'm looking for feedback on how to make the code faster (the glider gun provided slows down after making about 3 gliders), as well as error handling. I haven't implemented any yet, but I'm not sure how much I need to account for - does every function need a `try` ... `except` statement? Only every `__init__` function? Any feedback in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Here is [the code from a previous Q](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185040/conways-game-of-life-in-python-3-using-tkinter). I used this as a reference, but I tried my best not to directly copy it. However, some elements are quite similar to it (for example, both have 3 classes of Square/Cell, Grid and App).

I also have a problem with trying to import this module and changing the behaviour of ‘Cell’. To do this, I have been told to make a subclass, and override when needed. However, ‘Grid’ creates new cells using the original ‘Cell’ constructor, so any changes I make won’t affect the cells Grid creates.

Is there any way I can edit the behaviour of Cell and get Grid to make the new objects, without rewriting lots of functions?